# PostgreSQL updating one table from another

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

Edit: Sorry, I should have explained a tad better, the data is out of salesforce, dumped from the backend, the ID fields are alphanumeric [eg. 00190000010PBdSAAX], generally all are 18 in length & are always unique. I'll make some changes to data types, get rid of the quoted identifiers, and make some changes to the indexes, see how I go!

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5. I'm updating 1 table to another, both tables are identical in structure, one has 2 million records [target] and the other around 70k [source], which is basically just performing an update on existing and inserting any new records using a unique ID to check against.

It's taking a lot longer than I thought, even when there is nothing to update and it just scans over the records, it still takes 5 minutes & even longer when there is something to update, tried with and without indexing, joining the 2 fields in slightly different ways [both with just a WHERE and with actual JOIN]. just want to know if there is a better way of doing it or if I'm doing it just plain wrong, only been using Postgres for few days.

I know 5 minutes is no big deal [longer if it performs any updates], but its a similar process for about 9 other tables & this is a mid size example

both tables look like the below [but with different table names only]

```
CREATE TABLE public."Cases"
(
  "Past_Due__c" character varying(255),
  "Case_Age__c" character varying(255),
  "Next_Step_Due_Date__c" character varying(255),
  "Id" character varying(255),
  "AccountId" character varying(255),
  "Account_Number__c" character varying(255),
  "Account_Type__c" character varying(255),
  "CaseNumber" character varying(255),
  "CaseSubTypeDetail__c" character varying(255),
  "Case_Sub_Type__c" character varying(255),
  "Case_Type__c" character varying(255),
  "ClosedDate" character varying(255),
  "Collections_Step__c" character varying(255),
  "Customer_Number__c" character varying(255),
  "Next_Collections_Step__c" character varying(255),
  "Origin" character varying(255),
  "Priority" character varying(255),
  "Related_Complaint_Case__c" character varying(255),
  "Status__c" character varying(255),
  "Subject" text,
  "Type" character varying(255),
  "CreatedDate" character varying(255),
  "OwnerId" character varying(255),
  "ContactId" character varying(255),
  "Status" character varying(255),
  "Case_Comments__c" text,
  "Subscription__c" character varying(255),
  "Description" text,
  "Case_Outcome__c" text,
  "Case_Outcome_Reason__c" text,
  "Adjustment_Amount__c" character varying(255),
  "Product_Adjustment_Amount__c" character varying(255),
  "Product_Adjustment_Reason__c" character varying(255),
  "Service__c" character varying(255),
  "ParentId" character varying(255)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

The update script is below

```
update public."cases" t2
set past_due__c = t1.past_due__c, case_age__c = t1.case_age__c, next_step_due_date__c = t1.next_step_due_date__c, accountid = t1.accountid, account_number__c = t1.account_number__c, account_type__c = t1.account_type__c, casesubtypedetail__c = t1.casesubtypedetail__c, case_sub_type__c = t1.case_sub_type__c, case_type__c = t1.case_type__c, closeddate = t1.closeddate, collections_step__c = t1.collections_step__c, customer_number__c = t1.customer_number__c, next_collections_step__c = t1.next_collections_step__c, origin = t1.origin, priority = t1.priority, related_complaint_case__c = t1.related_complaint_case__c, status__c = t1.status__c, subject = t1.subject, type = t1.type, ownerid = t1.ownerid, contactid = t1.contactid, status = t1.status, case_comments__c = t1.case_comments__c, subscription__c = t1.subscription__c, description = t1.description, case_outcome__c = t1.case_outcome__c, case_outcome_reason__c = t1.case_outcome_reason__c, adjustment_amount__c = t1.adjustment_amount__c, product_adjustment_amount__c = t1.product_adjustment_amount__c, product_adjustment_reason__c = t1.product_adjustment_reason__c, service__c = t1.service__c, parentid = t1.parentid, billing_account__c = t1.billing_account__c, billing_account_credit_balance__c = t1.billing_account_credit_balance__c, billing_address__c = t1.billing_address__c, lastmodifiedbyid = t1.lastmodifiedbyid, lastmodifieddate = t1.lastmodifieddate
from   public."temp_update_cases" t1
where  t1.id = t2.id
```

Everything else I need to do I figured out but this one is killing me

Comment: also note that i havent touched any default settings, and i vacuum before running the update

Comment: Unrelated, but: you should **really** avoid quoted identifiers.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, verbose)`. [_Formatted_](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). See also http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions for more information on how to ask performance related questions.

Comment: `"Id" character varying(255),`doesn't look like a good idea (even *with* a PK constraind or an index on it). BTW: this looks more like a spreadsheet than a database table ...

Answer (score 1):

Your query is basically this:

```
update public."cases" t2
set  . . .
from   public."temp_update_cases" t1
where  t1.id = t2.id;
```

I would suggest indexes:

```
create index idx_cases_id on public."cases"(id);
create index idx_temp_updte_cases_id on public."temp_update_cases"(id);
```

Notes:

- I agree with the comments that the quoted identifiers are not a good idea.
- Your tables should have some sort of primary key.  A column called `id` is a good candidate.
- Often, `serial` is a better option for the primary key than a character string.